# cannot connect to sql database on shared server

Tags: asp.net

I have purchased a website that was installed on a dedicated server. I have now moved it to arvixe and was able to successfully restore the database on one of their shared servers. I am able to connect to the server from sql studio management studio 2008 by using the domain name (www.mydomain.com) and the username and password of the database account i setup in the arvixe control panel. However, I am not able to connect to the database with the application. I am able to see pages of the site that do not use the database. The application is using .net 3.5 so I have set the server to .net 2.0 with classic IIS. I have done lots of searching on the web and have read through many forums. I have tried every possible option for connection strings in web.config and still receive this same error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849719
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject) +4863021
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +376
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
      System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4223; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4223

Right now my connection strings are in the following format in web.config. I have one for appsettings and one for connectionstrings and have also added info to applicationsetting.cs:

```
          <appsettings>
          <add key="ConnStringWebsite" value="SERVER=www.mydomain.com;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx"/>
          <appsettings/>
          <connectionstrings>
          <add name="FantasyActionConnectionString" connectionString="SERVER=www.mydomain.com;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx"/>
          <connectionstrings/>
```

ApplicationSettings.cs

```
//Connection String
                private const string _CONNSERVER = @"www.mydomain.com";
                private const string _CONNDATABASE = "mydatabase";
                private const string _CONNUSERID = @"xxxxxx";
                private const string _CONNPASSWORD = "xxxxxx";
```

Comment: Hi - This is really a question for serverfault.com.  The stuff you cut/pasted from the error message is good advice: "Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."  ALSO: Are you really sure you want to set IIS to .Net 2.0???

Comment: Yah the name is what is called for in the code for the homepage. I'm not sure if I should be using .net2.0. Should I be on 4.0? Classic or integrated?

Comment: Your first step should be either changing the server to .NET 3.5 or 4.0 or dropping the application to 2.0. A lot of times there can be conflicts between the different frameworks. Another thing is with the connection. I'm pretty sure that your connection strings just need to call the name. So your CONNSERVER should be equal to ConnStringWebsite and your CONNDATABASE should be equal to FantasyActionCOnnectionString. You shouldn't need the userID or password connections. At least i don't when i use a set up like that

Comment: Ok, I have switched to .net 4.0 integrated. And I have updated ApplicationSettings.cs as follows: `private const string _CONNSERVER = @"ConnStringWebsite"; 
                private const string _CONNDATABASE = "FantasyActionConnectionString";` Still unable to connect to database.

Comment: Does anyone know if those "@" symbols need to be in there?